# Under what circumstances can a division expression reduce the number of rows in a query's result?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm experiencing a problem with a query that I've written.

Given a table with the schema:

```
create table somevals(division varchar(100), 
                      subdivision varchar(100), 
                      good float, 
                      bad float);
```

I would like to find, for each unique `(division, subdivision)`, the sum of good values, the sum of bad values, and the ratio of good to bad values. So, I wrote the query:

```
select division, subdivision, g, b, g / b as ratio
from (select division, subdivision, sum(good) as g, sum(bad) as b 
      from somevals
      group by division, subdivision
     ) as temp
```

The problem is that this returns far fewer rows than I would expect. However, if I remove the division (`g / b as ratio`), this query returns the correct number of rows in the result (about three times as many). None of the columns contain `Null` values. None of the `bad` values are less than or equal to zero, so `sum(bad)` will always be non-zero.

I am at a loss for how this could be happening. Under what circumstances can adding a division expression in the `select` statement reduce the number of rows in the result?

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot change the number of rows returned by changing the `SELECT` clause.  The problem *must* lie elsewhere.

If you're absolutely sure that's what's happening, I would run `DBCC` on the table to make sure it's not corrupted.